# XML tags - value of missing content

Tags: php, xml

I'm new to XML and couldn't find an answer to this exact question below on here. 
If the content of a tag is missing - does that mean that the content should be considered undefined because it's an unknown value or 0 because it definitely doesn't exist? Eg below - would the speed-limiter below be considered undefined and therefore unknown, or zero for not present?

```
<plane>
       <seats>314</seats>
       <captain>True</captain>
       <wheels>14</wheels>
       <speed_limiter />
       <Cabin_Crew>True</Cabin_Crew>
</plane>
```

Comment: What default value are you talking about? Please, provide some code examples.

Comment: This very much depends on the situation, you would have to refer to whoever created the data to see how they implemented it.  You could implement it in all sorts of ways for the same situation.